# Angular dynamic environment.ts for embedded/packaged application

Tags: angular, go, variables, dynamic, production-environment

I'm building a Golang based server/solution that will be installed and run by customers. The frontend/UI is being developed and uses the environment.ts settings are part of Angular. This works fine for local development, and static environments of the server we deploy for testing ( such as staging-001.company.com ) but means we need to run ng build and modify the builds for each environment.

The idea is customers would run the service as a container or os service and configure it via the environment or config file, such as BASE_URL=http://app.mycompany.com, it is not hosted by us in the end state.

How can Angular's environment become dynamic? The UI is served, but it cannot hit the API with these environment settings being hard coded.

Ideally, I'm wondering how I could use a os.env to configure the built JS base settings. The user hits the service on http://app.mycompany.com which also has /rest/api/${blah}, but the JS cannot connect as it might have http://localhost:8080/rest/api as the baseUrl for Angular.

Angular seems great as its a single page app and serving the dist folder is simple enough, but doesn't seem like it can work for an embedded system, customer run/self-hosted software for example. There must be a way to do this...

Comment: You cannot use envvars in you frontend build stage as its contents stored in build artifacts. Configure your index to use window.location as base url to api. Then compose routes at runtime

Comment: This only works when using a nodejs like runtime to get access to process.env, it doesn't cater to apps served by Go or any other HTTP server.